# Download content to the app when it starts for first time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, download, uiimageview

I have a doubt related with my app. My app takes like 5-10 seconds to download all the data from my web service and also from twitter using STTwitterAPI, and I download all this content when the app just starts. The question is: What you  would do during this 5-10 secs? Show an UIAlertView saying that the app is downloading content? Load an Image to a UIImageView and once the data is downloaded delete the UIImageView (I don´t know how to check that)? Is there any method that Apple provides to give a solution to this question?

I just thought about setting a NSTimer for the UIImageview or the NSAlertView, the problem is that if I keep adding data to the server, or depending the connection of the user that is downloading the data, maybe the UIImageView goes away before all the data is already download.

What would be the best solution? Does STTwitter have a method to check if all the data is downloaded?

Comment: MBProgressHUD + AFNetworking. Show loading view in front and dismiss it when AFNetworking tell you download finished.

Comment: I am going to read about these 2 API´s. Thank you very much!

Comment: @KudoCC the other problem will be with STTwitterAPI. I am using it and I don´t know if that API includes a way to check if it has finished downloading content...

Comment: I don't know the STTwitterAPI, you could edit your question and ask for other's help.

Comment: Can I suggest you use `SVProgressHUD` which is such a simple framework to use for beginners. It really makes it easy to start having HUDs in your program by using that framework. MBProgress is a nice one too, it is after all the parent of SVProgressHUD but MBProgress hud requires a little more work to get it working.

Have a look at my post for how you may implement and solve the two problems you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this fantastic HUD display singleton framework:

[SVProgressHUD by Sam Vermette](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD/), all you do is drag the folder into your xcode project. Then import the `.h` file where ever you want to display your message and then you can start displaying a heads up display which is what the overlay is called by simply calling a method from the singleton class like so `[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Doing Stuff"];`. It's as simple as that!

[image]

Then download a project called `AFNetworking`. [AFNetworking from github.](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)
in AFNetworking there are is a selector method that you can set to the  will be of interest to you. So with this framework its easy to establish a connection to your server, download the data and the framework gives you the option to set a `SUCCESS` method which will then call your success method as soon as the data has finished downloading from your server.

Here's what your code may look like.

```
-(void)startDownloadingData{
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Downloading data"];
    //add your AFNetworking connection here that downloads the data
    //...
    [serverRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestSucceeded:)];
    //...
}
-(void)requestSucceeded:(ASIHTTPRequest*)request{
switch (statusCode) {
    case 400:
    case 401:
    {

        [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"An error occurred";
        break;
    }
    case 200:{
        NSLog(@"Request Successful");
        [SVProgressHUD dismissWithSuccess:@"Done"];
    }
    default:{
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks really cool, the problem is that I also download the timeline of my twitter using the STTwitterAPI. How can I check also when all the data from STTwitterAPI has been downloaded?

Comment: Well then you will end up making multiple connection requests and thats fine, AFNetworking can handle multiple network requests and ONLY when everything has been downloaded, which AFNetwork will detect one by one as each one of your network requests come back, will you then be rest assured that all has been downloaded :)

I've pushed you in the right direction now you have a look at the AFNetworking framework, guaranteed it will have what you require.

Comment: @iOSAddicted You know that all data from STTwitterAPI has been downloaded when you reach either successBlock or errorBlock.

Comment: @nst thank you so much! Now everything works perfect!

Comment: @nst nice one nst for letting him know about the API's successblock :)